# How to pack OGG audio file to RIFF container?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, ogg, riff

I have an ogg audio file and some information which is saved as sequence of bytes. I need to pack this audio and information in a single container such as RIFF or something else. I'm searching solutions which can be written under .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Ogg is a container format. What you perhaps will want is either use some Ogg format tools to attach your data directly to existing file, or re-stream the data into different container format where you have tools to attach your data to.

The formats might be WAV/RIFF, Matroska, MP4. It also perhaps depends what is exactly this additional data, more like a thumbnail, or additional stream (user comments with timestamps etc).

A popular framework for such manipulation in .NET is DirectShow.NET library, but as you clarify your need, you might end up using a different tool.

See also a neighboring thread with a code snippet: [Ogg to Riff/Wave encoding with acm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609427/ogg-to-riff-wave-encoding-with-acm)

Answer (score 0):

[How to move Ogg file to Wav file with Ogg Vorbis data in C#](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,articles.aspx#how-to-ogg-to-wav-with-ogg)

```
    static void OggToWavWithOgg()
    {
        string fileName = @"e:\Down\fortuna.ogg";
        using (DsReader dr = new DsReader(fileName))
        {
            if (dr.HasAudio)
            {
                short oggFormatTag = 26479;
                IntPtr format = dr.ReadFormat();
                WaveFormat waveFormat = AudioCompressionManager.GetWaveFormat(format);
                IntPtr formatOgg = AudioCompressionManager.GetCompatibleFormat(format, oggFormatTag);
                using (WaveWriter ww = new WaveWriter(File.Create(fileName + ".wav"),
                    AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(formatOgg)))
                {
                    AudioCompressionManager.Convert(dr, ww, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```