# Ogg to Riff/Wave encoding with acm

Tags: c++, audio, wav, ogg, microsoft-acm

My task is to record wave file, convert it to ogg and pack it to the riff container. First two parts were done, but I have problems with the third part. I've found a source code which can solve my problem, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mmreg.h>
#include <msacm.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define INPUT       "record.wav"
#define OUTPUT  "output_ogg.wav"


/* The following taken from the vorbis.acm sources */
/* Defines modes for encoding. Set this in 'fmt '  */

#define WAVE_FORMAT_VORBIS1     ((WORD)'O'+((WORD)'g'<<8))  // 0x674f("Og") ... Original stream compatible
#define WAVE_FORMAT_VORBIS2     ((WORD)'P'+((WORD)'g'<<8))  // 0x6750("Pg") ... Have independent header
#define WAVE_FORMAT_VORBIS3     ((WORD)'Q'+((WORD)'g'<<8))  // 0x6751("Qg") ... Have no codebook header
#define WAVE_FORMAT_VORBIS1P    ((WORD)'o'+((WORD)'g'<<8))  // 0x676f("og") ... Original stream compatible
#define WAVE_FORMAT_VORBIS2P    ((WORD)'p'+((WORD)'g'<<8))  // 0x6770("pg") ... Have independent header
#define WAVE_FORMAT_VORBIS3P    ((WORD)'q'+((WORD)'g'<<8))  // 0x6771("qg") ... Have no codebook header


/* The 'fact' chunk required for compressed WAV files */
struct FACT {
unsigned long   dwID;
unsigned long   dwSize;
unsigned long   dwSamples;
};

int main()
{   
/* Open source file */
HMMIO hSrcWaveFile=mmioOpen(INPUT,NULL,MMIO_READ);
assert(hSrcWaveFile);

MMCKINFO SrcWaveFile;
mmioDescend(hSrcWaveFile,&SrcWaveFile,NULL,0);

assert(SrcWaveFile.ckid==mmioStringToFOURCC("RIFF",MMIO_TOUPPER));
assert(SrcWaveFile.fccType==mmioStringToFOURCC("WAVE",MMIO_TOUPPER));

MMCKINFO SrcWaveFmt;

/* Go to RIFF-WAVE*/
mmioDescend(hSrcWaveFile,&SrcWaveFmt,&SrcWaveFile,0);

assert(SrcWaveFmt.ckid==mmioStringToFOURCC("fmt ",0));

int SrcHeaderSize=SrcWaveFmt.cksize;

if(SrcHeaderSize<sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX))
    SrcHeaderSize=sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);

WAVEFORMATEX *SrcHeader=(WAVEFORMATEX *)new char[SrcHeaderSize];
ZeroMemory(SrcHeader,SrcHeaderSize);

/* Read fmt */
mmioRead(hSrcWaveFile,(char*)SrcHeader,SrcWaveFmt.cksize);

/* Leave the chunk */
mmioAscend(hSrcWaveFile,&SrcWaveFmt,0);

MMCKINFO SrcWaveData;
while(1){
    MMRESULT Result=mmioDescend(hSrcWaveFile,&SrcWaveData,&SrcWaveFile,0);
    assert(Result==0);
    if(SrcWaveData.ckid==mmioStringToFOURCC("data",0))
        break;
    Result=mmioAscend(hSrcWaveFile,&SrcWaveData, 0);
    assert(Result==0);
}

/* Destination header */
WAVEFORMATEX *DstHeader=(WAVEFORMATEX *)malloc(1024);
ZeroMemory(DstHeader,1024);

printf ("Going ACM!\n");

/* Suggest a format for us                             */
/* Try to coose the nmber 3 mode (whatever that is)    */

DstHeader->wFormatTag       =       WAVE_FORMAT_VORBIS3;
DstHeader->nChannels        =       2;
DstHeader->wBitsPerSample   =       16;
DstHeader->nSamplesPerSec   =       44100;

printf ("->acmFormatSuggest()\n");  
if (acmFormatSuggest(NULL,SrcHeader,DstHeader,1024,ACM_FORMATSUGGESTF_WFORMATTAG))
    printf ("ERROR: acmFormatSuggest()\n");

/* We shoudl have the DstHeader filled with data byt the ACM now */

/* Open destination */
HMMIO hDstWaveFile;

/* open the destination file */
hDstWaveFile=mmioOpen(OUTPUT,NULL,MMIO_CREATE|MMIO_WRITE);
assert(hDstWaveFile);
printf ("->mmioOpen() output.wav\n");

/* Create chunks */
MMCKINFO DstWaveFile;
DstWaveFile.fccType=mmioStringToFOURCC("WAVE",MMIO_TOUPPER);
mmioCreateChunk(hDstWaveFile,&DstWaveFile,MMIO_CREATERIFF);
printf ("->mmioCreateChunk() WAVE\n");

/* Create format chunk */
MMCKINFO DstWaveFmt;
DstWaveFmt.ckid=mmioStringToFOURCC("fmt ",0);

/* Create chunk write data and Ascend out of it */
mmioCreateChunk(hDstWaveFile,&DstWaveFmt,0);
printf ("->mmioCreateChunk() fmt\n");
mmioWrite(hDstWaveFile,(char*)DstHeader,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)+DstHeader->cbSize);
printf ("->mmioWrite() fmt header\n");
mmioAscend(hDstWaveFile,&DstWaveFmt,0);
printf ("->mmioAscend()\n");


/* fact chunk                                               */
/* this is only my idea of what it should look like         */
/* i found that some WAV files had more data than i write   */
/* but that seems enough for most of apps i tested          */

FACT DstFactChunk;
MMCKINFO FactChunk;

DstFactChunk.dwID       =   mmioStringToFOURCC ("fact", 0);
DstFactChunk.dwSamples  =   SrcWaveData.cksize / 4; 
DstFactChunk.dwSize     =   sizeof (DstFactChunk) - sizeof (DstFactChunk.dwID) - sizeof (DstFactChunk.dwSize);
FactChunk.ckid = mmioStringToFOURCC ("fact", 0);
FactChunk.cksize = DstFactChunk.dwSize;

/* Calculate the time */
float TIME;
if (SrcHeader->nSamplesPerSec == 44100)
    TIME = DstFactChunk.dwSamples / 44100.f;

mmioWrite (hDstWaveFile, (char *)&DstFactChunk, sizeof (DstFactChunk));

/* This ascend produced an error when i added this whole code               */
/* to my Dialog based MFC full feature super duper app                      */
/* Don't know why really but i think that Write already moves the pointer   */
/* past the chun sok this is unnecessery                                    */
/* mmioAscend (hDstWaveFile, &FactChunk, 0);                                */


/* Create Data chunk */
MMCKINFO DstWaveData;
DstWaveData.ckid=mmioStringToFOURCC("data",0);

mmioCreateChunk(hDstWaveFile,&DstWaveData,0);
mmioAscend (hDstWaveFile, &DstWaveData, 0);

printf ("->mmioCreateChunk() data\n");

/* Print the data we have gathered so far */
printf ("------------Source-----------\n");
printf ("Format: \t\t%X\n", SrcHeader->wFormatTag);
printf ("Channels: \t\t%d\n", SrcHeader->nChannels);
printf ("Samples/Sec: \t\t%d\n", SrcHeader->nSamplesPerSec);
printf ("AverageBytes/Sec: \t%d\n", SrcHeader->nAvgBytesPerSec);
printf ("Bits/Sample: \t\t%d\n", SrcHeader->wBitsPerSample);
printf ("BlockAlign: \t\t%d\n", SrcHeader->nBlockAlign);
printf ("DataSize: \t\t%d\n", SrcWaveData.cksize);
printf ("Time: \t\t\t%.3f\n", TIME);
printf ("Samples: \t\t%d\n", DstFactChunk.dwSamples);
printf ("Extra: \t\t\t%d\n", SrcHeader->cbSize);
printf ("------------------------------\n");

printf ("\n------------Destination------\n");
printf ("Format: \t\t%X\n", DstHeader->wFormatTag);
printf ("Channels: \t\t%d\n", DstHeader->nChannels);
printf ("Samples/Sec: \t\t%d\n", DstHeader->nSamplesPerSec);
printf ("AverageBytes/Sec: \t%d\n", DstHeader->nAvgBytesPerSec);
printf ("Bits/Sample: \t\t%d\n", DstHeader->wBitsPerSample);
printf ("BlockAlign: \t\t%d\n", DstHeader->nBlockAlign);
printf ("Extra: \t\t\t%d\n", DstHeader->cbSize);
printf ("------------------------------\n");


DWORD maxFormatSize = 0;
MMRESULT ACMres;

/* Get the max possbile size from the system this really no necessery */
/* but i was experimenting a bit and so I left it here                */

ACMres = acmMetrics( NULL, ACM_METRIC_MAX_SIZE_FORMAT, &maxFormatSize );

if (ACMres != MMSYSERR_NOERROR){
    printf ("ERROR: acmMetrics()\n");
}

/* Open ACM stream */
HACMSTREAM acm = NULL;
MMRESULT Result=acmStreamOpen(&acm,NULL,SrcHeader,DstHeader,NULL,0,0,0);
printf ("->acmStreamOpen()\n");

if (Result != MMSYSERR_NOERROR){
    printf ("ERROR: acmStreamOpen()\n");
    exit (-1);
}


/* This is where the problem's begin, first the buffers  */
/* Size of the dest/src is based on the size of src/dest */
DWORD DefaultWriteSize;
DWORD DefaultReadSize = SrcHeader->nBlockAlign * 1024;

/* If we know the dest */
/* Result=acmStreamSize(acm, DefaultWriteSize, &DefaultReadSize, ACM_STREAMSIZEF_DESTINATION); */


printf ("->acmStreamSize()\n");

/* If we know the source, well stay with the source PCM is less problematic */

Result = acmStreamSize (acm, DefaultReadSize, &DefaultWriteSize, ACM_STREAMSIZEF_SOURCE);

printf ("->acmStreamSize() gave us buffer size [%d]\n", DefaultWriteSize);

if (Result != MMSYSERR_NOERROR){
    printf ("ERROR: acmStreamSize()\n");
    exit (-1);
}

/* Allocate memory */
ACMSTREAMHEADER stream;
ZeroMemory(&stream,sizeof(stream));
stream.cbStruct=sizeof(stream);
stream.pbSrc=(BYTE*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,DefaultReadSize);
stream.cbSrcLength=DefaultReadSize;
stream.pbDst=(BYTE*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,DefaultWriteSize);
stream.cbDstLength=DefaultWriteSize;

/* Prepare header */
printf ("->acmStreamPrepareHeader()\n");
Result=acmStreamPrepareHeader(acm, &stream,0);
if (Result != MMSYSERR_NOERROR){
    printf ("ERROR: acmStreamPrepareHeader()\n");
    exit (-1);
}


/* The main encoding loop                                                       */
/* I'm pretty sure that before the actual reading of samples from the source    */
/* I should feed the ACM some junk so that it would write the necessery headers */
/* that Ogg Vorbis requires                                                     */
/* but i dont know how much of that 'junk' i would have to write there          */
/* i don't know if it can be junk                                               */
/* well i'm pretty clueless here                                                */

for(int RemainSize=SrcWaveData.cksize;RemainSize>0;){
    // ????
    int ReadSize=DefaultReadSize;

    if(ReadSize>RemainSize)
        ReadSize=RemainSize;

    RemainSize-=ReadSize;


    ReadSize=mmioRead(hSrcWaveFile,(char*)stream.pbSrc,ReadSize);
    if (ReadSize == -1){
        printf ("Can't read\n");
        break;
    }

    stream.cbSrcLength=ReadSize;

    /* Convert */
    Result=acmStreamConvert(acm,&stream,0);
    if (Result)
        printf ("ERROR: acmStreamConvert()\n");

    int WriteSize=stream.cbDstLengthUsed;

    /* Wrtie data */
    Result=mmioWrite(hDstWaveFile,(char*)stream.pbDst,WriteSize);

    if (Result == -1){
        printf ("Can't Write");
        break;
    }

    /* Uncomment this if you want to see the buffer sizes */
    /* printf ("READ[%d] :: WRITE[%d]\n", stream.cbSrcLengthUsed, stream.cbDstLengthUsed); */

    }


/* Cleaup on Isle 5 !!! */

    GlobalFree(stream.pbSrc);
    GlobalFree(stream.pbDst);
    acmStreamUnprepareHeader(acm,&stream,0);

    acmStreamClose(acm,0);

    mmioAscend(hSrcWaveFile,&SrcWaveData,0);
    mmioAscend(hSrcWaveFile,&SrcWaveFile,0);

    mmioAscend(hDstWaveFile,&DstWaveData,0);
    mmioAscend(hDstWaveFile,&DstWaveFile,0);

    free(DstHeader);

    mmioClose(hSrcWaveFile,0);
    mmioClose(hDstWaveFile,0);

    delete[] SrcHeader;

    return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying to execute this program, it shows me that acmFormatSuggest() and acmStreamOpen() failes. Please, help me finding the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acmFormatSuggest (by the way, what is the error code?) would possibly succeed if there is an ACM audio codec installed, which supports this format. There is no one available by default, do you actually have one installed?

Comment: Absolutely. ACM API does not know anything about Vorbis. More to that, Windows SDK does not have any better idea what Vorbis might be all about (note you have to #define Vorbis formats in code). So codec availability is a must.

Comment: I've added Vorbis ACM codec to my system, but nothing changed. Even after restart. Maybe there are any other problems?

Comment: How do you know it is installed? What was the download link? What error codes you are getting? Are you sure you are not confusing Win32/x64 binaries? Details are missing and they are important.

Comment: I have downloaded codec here: http://www.free-codecs.com/download/Vorbis_Ogg_ACM.htm

Comment: As I understand, the acmFormatSuggest(NULL,SrcHeader,DstHeader,1024,ACM_FORMATSUGGESTF_WFORMATTAG) returns true.

Comment: Possible causes for the function to still fail include: (a) codec is not actually installed (b) source audio format is not supported input for the codec.

Comment: Do I need to write the path to the codec or acm can find it itself if it is installed?

Comment: Check its readme-eng.txt, Installation section. And make sure you run this code against PCM encoded file. You should at least pass acmFormatSuggest without error then.

Comment: Thank you for help. Codec didn't installed correctly. I've tried to execute under other system and it works.

Comment: @AlexanderTaraymovich can you accept this answer to close this question?

Comment: @Wimmel Yes, answer can be closed